# how to comment in jade coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, pug

I am trying to use the coffeescript in jade and ### doesn't seem to work. and the block level comment of jade within coffeescript doesn't allow me to comment a set of lines. it just allows a complete block based of indentation commented. any suggestions???

thanks

Comment: Do you mean inside of a CoffeeScript filter in your jade file?

Comment: yes adding comment within coffeescript filter

Comment: Are you sure you used the `###` comments correctly? Take a look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`###` comments seems to work for me (don't forget this is for multilines comments so you need to close them):

```
!!! 5
html(lang='en')
  head
    title App

  body  
    :coffeescript
      ### Comment ###
      require "index"
      ###
      Comment 2
      ###
```

compiles to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>App</title>
  </head>
  <body> <script type="text/javascript">

/* Comment
*/

(function() {

  require("index");

  /*
  Comment 2
  */

}).call(this);
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to edit your answer to point out that the closing `###` is *required*, even in a single-line comment. That was probably what the OP was doing wrong. `### ... ###` in CoffeeScript is like `/* ... */` in C. To make a single-line comment like `// ...`, you would use a single hash, like this: `# ...`.

Comment: Thx I'll add it to the answer

Comment: I think that was the problem and it need to be indent accordingly..thanks